# Weird faces- any tricks

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, faces, topology

Is any fast fix for this? without doing retopology or deleting this part and doing this manually.
[image]

Comment: Try the function "Tris to Quads" if it helps to tidy up...

Comment: it worked for around half.

Comment: You could try deleting the weird strip, selecting both edges, then using [*bridge edge loops*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html#modeling-meshes-editing-bridge-edge-loops)

Comment: That worked. Thanks